# How to export data from hive to kafka

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-kafka

I need to export data from Hive to Kafka topics based on some events in another Kafka topic. I know I can read data from hive in Spark job using HQL and write it to Kafka from the Spark, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using unstructured streaming. The steps mentioned below :

1. Create a Spark Streaming  Job which connects to the required topic and fetched the required data export information.
2. From stream , do a collect and get your data export requirement in Driver variables.
3. Create a data frame using the specified condition
4. Write the data frame into the required topic using kafkaUtils.
5. Provide a polling interval based on your data volume and kafka write throughputs.

Comment: We might be streaming close to 10 million records. Do you think this approach is the most optimal? I was asking if there are hadoop components like sqoop which can take a hive query and write directly to Kafka, without bringing records in memory of a Spark process.

Comment: You can use Flink, If you use Cloud, Firehouse in aws and Stream Analytics for Azure can work similar. But for Custom application in Databricks or Hadoop applications, this is the only way

Comment: @Srijit Even Sqoop would require bringing records into memory

Comment: @cricket_007 But as I understand Sqoop will run in Hadoop cluster and Spark in its own cluster. By using Sqoop I am not overwhelming Spark. May be I am wrong in that assumption.

Comment: @Srijit No, Spark on YARN will occupy the same physical resources as Sqoop (Mapreduce) on YARN

Comment: Sqoop is used for data migration from RDBMS, it uses distributed file system and Java Heap memory . Spark is a data processing engine. If I understood your requirement, what you want to achieve , there is no ready made tool available for now. You can check a paid tool called Striim

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think we will go ahead with the Spark approach now. As a future design we may also look at Couchbase as alternate to Hive. Thanks @cricket_007 for the couchbase idea

Comment: @Srijit It's not really clear how you plan on making Spark not re-read the same data in Hive, but good luck!

Comment: Basically the requirement is to publish some companion data from hive, for the incoming data. This data need to be published on different Kafka topics so that subsequent joins on KafkaStreams will work. 

We get the keys of the data that we need from hive in the Spark application via Kafka. So, I am planning on executing HQL against the Hive tables in the Spark job and stream the RDD to the subsequent topics. I really wished there was some component that will stream directly from Hive to Kafka given the HQL

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you do this the other way around (Kafka to HDFS/Hive).

But you are welcome to try using the Kafka Connect JDBC plugin to read from a Hive table on a scheduled basis, which converts the rows into structured key-value Kafka messages.

Otherwise, I would re-evaulate other tools because Hive is slow. Couchbase or Cassandra offer much better CDC features for ingestion into Kafka. Or re-write the upstream applications that inserted into Hive to begin with, rather to write immediately into Kafka, from which you can join with other topics, for example.